# Convert and import sql file into postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to migrate database from mysql to postgresql. So, first did the `mysqldump` with this command

```
mysqldump -u root -p --compatible=postgresql --default-character-set=utf8  databasename > output.sql
```

Then i upload the output.sql to host and import the sql file using below command

```
psql -U root -d databasename -f /home/test/output.sql
```

But i got error when i try to import

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "KEY"   
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNLOCK"  
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("       
invalid command \n        
invalid command \'></script>       
invalid command \";s:2:          
invalid command \',        
invalid command \']       
Query buffer reset (cleared).
```

The size of database that I dumped is 7.5gb.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL used in MySQL and that used in Postgres are not one-to-one inter-compatible. You need a converter program for anything non-trivial.

From the documentation for `--compatible`:

> This option does not guarantee compatibility with other servers.

In other words, it's only *slightly* more compatible.

There are commercial products like [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/) which can help do this for you automatically, or you can dump out all your MySQL data in a neutral format like XML, JSON or CSV and read it back in using some other tool.